# Scikeras : error when loading a saved model from StackingRegressor with Keras Regressor among estimators

Tags: python, keras, save, pickle

I run a small regression task with a KerasRegressor (on Windows). I'm using a StackingRegressor and save the model.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import MeanSquaredError
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

def show_results(history):
    # split val loss
    loss = history['loss']
    val_loss = history['val_loss']
    # Create the plot
    plt.plot(loss)
    plt.plot(val_loss)
    plt.xlabel("Epoch")
    plt.ylabel("Loss")
    plt.title('Model accuracy')
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.show()

def model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(
        units = 10,
        activation="relu",
        input_dim = 3
        ))
    model.add(Dense(
        units = 10,
        activation="relu",
        ))
    model.add(Dense(
        units = 1,
        activation="linear"
        ))
    opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
    model.compile(
        optimizer = opt,
        loss="mse",
        metrics=[MeanSquaredError()]
        )
    return model

# create model
reg = KerasRegressor(model=model,
                            batch_size=64,
                            epochs=200,
                            verbose=0)


X_regr, y_regr = make_regression(300, 3, n_informative=10, random_state=0)
X_regr = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_regr)
print(X_regr.shape, y_regr.shape,X_regr.min(), X_regr.max(), y_regr.min(), y_regr.max())
hist = reg.fit(X_regr, y_regr, validation_split=0.2)
print(hist.history_)

show_results(hist.history_)

from sklearn.ensemble import StackingRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor
estimators = [
    ('ada', AdaBoostRegressor(estimator=reg, random_state=0, n_estimators=2)),
    ('bag', BaggingRegressor(estimator=reg,n_estimators=2, random_state=0))
]

stacking = StackingRegressor(estimators=estimators, cv=2))

stacking.fit(X_regr, y_regr)
stacking_score = stacking.score(X_regr, y_regr)
print(f"Stacking score: {stacking_score:.2f}")

import  pickle
filename = "scikeras.pkl"
pickle.dump(stacking, open(filename, 'wb')) 
pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

But when I load it, I got the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OpError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 79
     78 pickle.dump(stacking, open(filename, 'wb')) 
---> 79 pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb')) 

File scikeras\_saving_utils.py:50, in unpack_keras_model(packed_keras_model)
     48             f.write(archive.extractfile(fname).read())
     49 model: keras.Model = load_model(temp_dir)
---> 50 model.load_weights(temp_dir)
     51 model.optimizer.build(model.trainable_variables)
     52 return model

File keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File tensorflow\python\training\py_checkpoint_reader.py:45, in error_translator(e)
     43   raise errors_impl.InternalError(None, None, error_message)
     44 else:
---> 45   raise errors_impl.OpError(None, None, error_message, errors_impl.UNKNOWN)

OpError:
```

Did I do something wrong? Is there a work-a-round?
The problem appears when loading Keras weights, but it's not clear to me why it doesn't work or what is missing. It seems that we can save the KerasRegressor object https://adriangb.com/scikeras/refs/heads/master/notebooks/Basic_Usage.html#3.1-A-toy-regression-task but what about trained ensemble models from sklearn?
Thanks for your help